# firebase authentication in vue js app shows error

Tags: vue.js, firebase-authentication, vue-router

Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined

### Mail.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import firebase from "firebase";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

let firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "qqq",
  authDomain: "qqq",
  databaseURL: "qqq",
  projectId: "qqq",
  storageBucket: "qqq",
  messagingSenderId: "qqq",
  appId: "qqq",
  measurementId: "qqq"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

The above code is added in mail.js inside the src folder.

After that, I have added a `Register` Vue

**Register.vue:**

```
<template>
<div class="sign-up">
<form @submit.prevent="register">
<input type="email" v-model="email" placeholder="Type your email" />
<input type="password" v-model="password" placeholder="Pick your password" />
<button> Sign Up </button>
</form>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import "firebase/auth";

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        };
    },
    methods: {
        register() {
            alert(this.email)
        } 
    }
}
</script>
```

I the register vue file I have registered a form and use firebase the function is working fine with an alert message as above, but when I use `firebase.auth()` it shows error i.e.

> firebase is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the firebase library and/or API you're using. But there is no `firebase` defined in your Register.vue so the ReferenceError is expected.

You import "firebase/auth" in your component, not firebase. Looks to me like you should instead repeat the firebase import you're using in your Mail.js:

```
import firebase from "firebase";

export default {
    ...
    methods: {
        register() {
            firebase.auth(...);
...
```